# Hosting a tomcat site - port forwarding

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, apache2, tomcat

I have a desktop running a tomcat site (jira). When I go to 192.168.1.108:8080 from a device on my network I can see the site.

I now want to be able to access it through internet. For that purpose I have set up a port forwarding rule on my router, that will take connections on port range 8080 .. 8090 and forward them to IP 192.168.1.108 (need to get 2 more sites up).

When I try to access them from the internet using my dns or IP (like 1.1.1.1:8080), I get the loading icon on tab for quite some time, and then 'page not available'. Entering just the IP takes me to router page.

If I remove the port forwarding rule from router, I get 'page not available' immediately, which makes me believe something is actually going on...

Are there any steps that I am missing ? Do I need to change any settings on the server running the site ?

The server uses ubuntu server 14.04..

Comment: Are you able to host a simple page on port 80 and try that out?  You can also try changing [Jira's port to 80](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Changing+JIRA%27s+TCP+Ports) and trying that.  If it works, consider using [Apache as a proxy](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/77812/forward-domain-to-jira-ip-works-but-not-with-port-8080-added) for your applications.  (Out of curiosity is it Stash, Jira, Confluence?)

Comment: Just Jira but will be running bamboo. I have tried forwarding just port 80, which should bring up default apache page, but that  is also not working

Comment: Does the fact that my modem is connected to a router, and the router to the server make any difference? SkyHub (this is where I add the forward rule) > Router > server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to port forward from Internet to your web server, you can't have a NAT behind a NAT.
To figure that out, your routers external address must be the same as seen when you surf on internet.

So log into your router and look up what IPv4 address you have on your external interface. You might get help from this site, it has worked for me before: http://portforward.com/

Then you have to see what address other servers see when you surf out from your LAN, behind the router.  I use this siter, but there are others:
http://www.whatismyip.com/

It the first are a private address and/or those two addresses are not the same, then your modem is giving you a private address and not a public one.  That makes it impossible (or at least hard) to make your server accessable from Internet.

The solution for both your problems are of course IPv6, as you will not give you a private address but a real public /64 network of IPv6 addresses for your LAN.  And as many servers as you like, or actually (2 to the power of 64) - 2, which is quite a lot. ;-)